# The value sent to ajax does not change

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have an html that prints out multiple forms with saved values/labels from the database

```
<?php
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM product");
if ($stmt->execute()){
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){

?>
    <div class="col-xl-3 col-md-4 mb-4">
        <div class="card border-bottom-secondary h-100">
            <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                <img src="img/<?php echo $img_src; ?>" alt="" class="card-img-top embed-responsive-item">
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <form>
                    <div>
                        <h4 class="text-primary"><?php echo $row['name']; ?></h4>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="<?php echo $row['name']; ?>" hidden>
                        <label for="quantity">Qty. </label>
                        <input class="w-25" onclick="this.select();" min="1" name="quantity" value="1" type="number" id="quantity">
                        <button type="button" id="save" onclick="saveTemp()">Add</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php 
    }
}
?>
```

Now here is my saveTemp() function which stores it in a database:

```
function saveTemp() {
var productName = $('#name').val();
var quantity = $('#quantity').val();
//console.log(productName);
//console.log(quantity);
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "purchase.php",
    data: {
        product: productName,
        quantity: quantity
    },
    success: function(){
        alert('success');
    }

});
return false;
}
```

The problem is that whenever I click on a different form to send, the values in productName and quantity don't change. They still contain the values of the first printed form.

Example:

Suppose the first card contains fries and the next card contains burgers, even if I click the Add button on the burgers, the inserted value in the database is still fries and its quantity, not the burgers.

PS. Here's my simple purchase.php script if it helps. Thank you!

```
<?php
include_once('connect.php');
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
    $product = $_POST['product'];
    $quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
    $insert = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO cart (name, quantity) VALUES (?,?)");
    $insert->bind_param("si", $product, $quantity);
    $insert->execute();
    $insert->close();
}
```

Comment: `id`s need to be unique, yours are not because they are in a loop

Comment: Sidenote: You can write ```<?=$img_src?>``` instead of ```<?php echo $img_src;?>```. ```<?=``` is shorthand for ```<?php echo```.

Comment: how would i go about making the id unique?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the separate form id like following...

**View**

```
<?php
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM product");
if ($stmt->execute()){
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    $i = 1; // added
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){

?>
    <div class="col-xl-3 col-md-4 mb-4">
        <div class="card border-bottom-secondary h-100">
            <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                <img src="img/<?php echo $img_src; ?>" alt="" class="card-img-top embed-responsive-item">
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <form id="saveform<?=$i?>"> <!-- form id added -->
                    <div>
                        <h4 class="text-primary"><?php echo $row['name']; ?></h4>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="<?php echo $row['name']; ?>" hidden>
                        <label for="quantity">Qty. </label>
                        <input class="w-25" onclick="this.select();" min="1" name="quantity" value="1" type="number" id="quantity">
                        <button type="button" id="save" onclick="saveTemp(this)">Add</button> <!-- pass 'this' from here-->
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php 
    $i++; //incremented here
  }
}
?>
```

make this changed in your script...

**js**

```
function saveTemp(these) {
var formId = $(these).closest("form").attr("id"); // get form id here
var productName = $('#'+formId+' #name').val(); // assigned form id here
var quantity = $('#'+formId+' #quantity').val(); // assigned form id here
//console.log(productName);
//console.log(quantity);
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "purchase.php",
    data: {
        product: productName,
        quantity: quantity
    },
    success: function(){
        alert('success');
    }

});
return false;
}
```

Comment: any changes to the php script? the variables are getting undefined so nothing gets saved in the database. Also, i think it does not work. Console log says js variables are undefined.

Comment: did you get value in `consol.log `

Comment: No. Console log says undefined.

Comment: make sure you put formId in this line `$('#'+formId+' #name').val();`

Comment: yes i did, i also console.log the var formId to check and it does give a different saveform# however, the other variables are still undefined.

Comment: make sure you put space before `#name` here `$('#'+formId+' #name').val();`

Comment: Yes! Thank you. I realized I was missing the space between them. I thought it can be ignored since I'm new and i don't know how it works. Thank you so much!